# Raising and lowering indices on the derivative operator

Tags: calculus, intuition, tensors

So I've learnt, we can 'raise' and 'lower' indices of the derivative operator in the following way:

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\alpha} } = g^{\alpha \beta} \frac{\partial }{\partial x_{\beta}}$$

Alternately:

$$ g_{\alpha \beta} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha } } = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\beta} }$$

Source: Eqtn 16.24 of [this site](https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/Class/phy319/phy319/node131.html).

To contradict the above, this point is discussed at 1:20:39 in [lecture 5a](https://youtu.be/TC98KfiGAOk?t=4839) on Tensor Calculus by Pavel Grinfeld at 1:20:39, where he states that only $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}$ exists (as he says, you can only take derivative with respect to coordinates)

My question is does such a thing as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\beta} }$ exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensor notations vary wildly from source to source so it gets hard to keep track of what people mean by what they write! Since you are familiar with Pavel Grinfeld, I will try to invoke his notation. I agree with him that a true "partial derivative" should be taken with respect to the coordinates which are innately contravariant entities. My immediate guess is that they are using their notation to extend the contravariant derivative. We know that the covariant derivative is

$$ \nabla_k \: A^j = \dfrac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial x^k} \cdot \vec{Z}^j  $$

and that a contravariant derivative is defined as

$$ \nabla^\ell \: A^j = Z^{k\ell} \: \nabla_k \: A^j = Z^{k\ell} \: \dfrac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial x^k} \cdot \vec{Z}^j \text{ .}$$

We could then say that $$  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_\ell} := Z^{k\ell} \: \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^k} $$

is an operator that does to a vector what the contravariant derivative does to the components of that vector.

Comment: I realize that I did mix notation a little bit but I think this is for the best. If it is unclear, $x^k$ are the coordinates that Grinfeld calls $z^k$.

Comment: I think you have written covariant  derivative in cartesian? If it were non cart then you would need the christoffel symbols I think. Secondly, in the last equation, shouldn't it be covariant metric tensor bcz u want the 'index' on derivative to be 'lowered'?

Comment: @Buraian, the Christoffel symbol is baked into the covariant derivative. Looking at my first expression, if $\vec{A}$ is contravariant then
$$ \dfrac{\partial\vec{A}}{\partial x^k} =  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^k} (A^j \vec{Z}_j)$$
where the product rule will produce the Christoffel symbols. Secondly, I would argue that my second line of MathJax leads to the natural definition that the contravariant metric should be used. Additionally, I would argue that an upper index in the denominator is a lower index in the numerator and vice versa.

Comment: @Buraian, also if you notice the expressions as you have them don't work with Einstein convention or the standard sense of "contravariant" and "covariant". This leads one to believe that they are bad tensor expressions. Reading through the website you linked, it feels like a typo.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh I see now

Comment: Now I understand it mechanistically, but could you explain the difference in physical interpretation of these two?

Comment: @Buraian, it may help to think of it as taking $n$ differential 1-forms from the dual space into the tangent space. A contravariant derivative would describe $n$ vectors rather than $n$ functionals.